# How to store an array on the page during session

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I'd like to ask a high-level question. Any directional advice will be welcome.

So, here is what I did in vanilla JS. I defined an empty variable first, and put the results of a DB query there. Then created buttons I did filter operations to only populate the items that satisfied the filter criteria. So, to illustrate, it looks like this:

```
 const things = [
    {continent: Asia, country: Korea},
    {continent: Europe, country: France},
    {continent: Africa, country: Egypt},
    .....
 ];
 const filter (continent) = > {
     //Logic to filter based on continent criteria and return the countries
 };
```

This was possible in vanilla JS, because I could set aside the array variable in the script document and the functions would easily reference it.

The question is: how do I do something similar in react? i.e. what would be an equivalent way to store a variable that lasts as long as the page is active, so that I can do filter operations on them? Obviously, setting aside a variable outside of the component doesn't work after the page is rendered. Where should I look to resolve this?

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: React uses "Vanilla JS" except the JSX part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can either do one of three things

1. Pass an array defined at the top level between children and
   parents (can work for simple pages)
2. Use the React Context Api
   https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html
3. Look into a state  management library like Redux (most recommended if your application is complex) -
   https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started/

Comment: local State, context, redux store... everything is gonna expire once your page is reloaded(CTRL + R). So if you want a storage, a level furthur, use SessionStorage. You should be able to save extra DB calls on reload as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to write data on a page server-side, and then load it into a React component client-side. I would try writing the data into a hidden element, probably in csv format, with an "id". Then, when your App component loads, use document.getElementById to retrieve the data. Pass that into your component tree, and filter away.

Sorry, I'm not able to test this out at the moment. There may be some gotchas with this approach, but if you don't want to fetch the data client-side, hopefully something like this will work.